# How to write a SQL query to find the first time when sum greater than a number？

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgresql table:

```
create table orders
(
     id int, 
     cost int, 
     time timestamp
);
```

How to write a PostgreSQL query to find the first time when `sum(cost)` is greater than 200？

For example：

```
id cost time
------------------
1  120  2019-10-10
2  50   2019-11-11
3  80   2019-12-12
4  60   2019-12-16
```

The first time `sum(cost)` greater than 200 is 2019-12-12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PostgreSQL, you can get this result by using a `CTE` to calculate the SUM of `cost` for rows up to and including the current one, and then selecting the first row which has total cost >= 200:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT time,
         SUM(cost) OVER (ORDER BY time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS total
  FROM data
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE total >= 200
ORDER BY total
LIMIT 1
```

Output:

```
time        total
2019-12-12  250
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c717c/3)

Comment: niubility! Perfect answer!

Comment: @GordonLinoff **Thank you** for pointing out the problem. I'm just happy to know the issue. I've corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of Nick's answer (which would be correct with an `ORDER BY`).  However, this version is  more efficient:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             sum(d.cost) over (order by d.time) as running_cost
      from d
     ) d
where running_cost - cost < 200 and
      running_cost >= 200;
```

Note that this *does not* require an `order by` in the outer query to work correctly.

There is also almost a way to solve this without using a subquery:

```
select o.*
from orders o
order by (sum(cost) over (order by time) >= 200) desc,
         time asc
limit 1;
```

The only issue is that this will return a row if no row matches the condition.  You could get around this by using a subquery in the `limit`:

```
limit (case when (select sum(cost) from orders) >= 400 then 1 else 0 end)
```

But then a subquery would be needed.

Comment: there will be an error if has duplicated time [postgres-doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html)

Comment: @球状闪电 . . . There won't be an *error*.  If you have duplicated times, then you should probably use `order by time, id` in the `order by` clause so it is stable.